# How do I locate a C library header file from a Makefile.PL?

Tags: c, perl, makefile

How can I locate a C library header file from a Makefile.PL?

There is ExtUtils::Liblist to find libraries, but I can't see the equivalent for header files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Devel::CheckLib`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::CheckLib) is what most authors seem to be use for that. It checks both for the existance of libraries as well as header files, as those libraries are probably useless without them.

Comment: OK, but it seems to fail some tests.

Comment: Also this doesn't seem to tell me where the include file is, it just tests whether it exists.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. It searches the configured include paths for a given header. If it's not there, including it will fail. Blindly guesing where it might be and configuring the cflags accordingly is also wrong. What one wants is either things just working and header files being in the right include paths, or the user to explicitly state additional include paths. Both those things are supported by `Devel::CheckLib`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this looks like something which I would not actually use in practice. Since nobody else has offered any answers to the question, I'll mark this as accepted for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a small lib to do this (and let it live in inc/lib/FindHeaders.pm or some such under the top level of your package dir).  Just use Config (see incpath) along with File::Find and glob and you should be able to have a small library which can walk your default include path and map a hash of header files on your system, returning it to a call from Makefile.PL.  It would be trivial to extend this to include non-standard include paths as well with a constructor argument to your lib.  Easy peasy.

Comment: I want to find the headers on other people's systems, so that I can write a Perl module which can be installed on their systems.